# How would a non list comprehension version of this code be?

Tags: python-3.x, list-comprehension

I am a beginner in python and figuring out ways to know the nuts and bolts.

not able to figure a non list comprehension version of this statement

```py
[(u, v) for u, v, d in T.edges(data=True) if d['date'] < date(2010, 1, 1)]
```

what I knew was manipulating the output expression but here the output expression is probably being generated only when the iterable meets a certain condition. Please clarify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general idea with list comprehension is that:

```py
[result for elements in iterable if condition]
```

translates to:

```py
ret = []
for elements in iterable:
    if condition:
        ret.append(result)
```

For example:

```py
[x for x in range(10,20) if x%3 == 0]
# => [12, 15, 18]
```

Works exactly in the same way as:

```py
ret=[]
for x in range(10,20):
    if x%3 == 0:
        ret.append(x)

ret # => [12, 15, 18]
```